# How to Extract Values from php array

Tags: php

I'm trying to return the LARGEST numerical value associated with the 'reduced' array below. Easy enough if there is one value but many have two- as below. I'm using

```
$reduced_array = $data['rates'][1]['rates'][0];
```

but this only works in returning the first value. I need to return just the highest value however- so below it would be 8.
would something like

```
 if(count($data['rates'][1]['rates']) > 2) {
        ***return largest value here***
```

work? I'm just not sure how to perform the asterisked task- maybe a for loop? here is the array.

```
Array
(
[rates] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Super Reduced
                [rates] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Reduced
                [rates] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 5
                        [1] => 8
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Standard
                [rates] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 23
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [name] => Increased
                [rates] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [name] => Parking
                [rates] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

[disclaimer] => Rates data is based on information published by the European Commission, updated 1st January 2017.
)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just grab the `rates` array, [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) it in descending order, then grab the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`max()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) for that.

```
$array = array(
    "rates" => array(
        array(
            "name" => "Super Reduced",
            "rates" => array()
        ),
        array(
            "name" => "Reduced",
            "rates" => array(
                5,
                8
            )
        )
    )
);

echo max($array["rates"][1]["rates"]); // 8
```

Comment: ah thanks, should have checked the php manual sorry, haven't programmed in quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution will be using of max on inner array
example:

```
if(!empty($data['rates'][1]['rates'])) {
    $maxvalue = max($data['rates'][1]['rates']);
}
```